# Character does not stop moving when movement key is released in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Relatively simple, I am a beginner at pygame and am not quite sure why when i release the "d" key, my character does not stop moving right. Same thing happens when moving left however, when moving left if i press "d" my character will move right but i cant make it move left again by pressing "a".
From what i can tell, i have all the necessary code for when a key is released but could be wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = int(SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.8)

screen= pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Fodian")

#Set framerate
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

#Game Variables
GRAVITY = 0.75

#Define player action variables
moving_left = False
moving_right = False

#Define colours
BG = (144,201,120)
RED = (255,0,0)

def draw_bg():
    screen.fill(BG)
    pygame.draw.line(screen,RED,(0,600),(SCREEN_WIDTH,600))

class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,scale,speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        img = pygame.image.load('Foddian/Foddian_Char.png')
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(img,(int(img.get_width()*scale),int(img.get_height()*scale)))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center =(x,y)
        self.alive = True
        self.speed = speed
        self.direction = 1
        self.vel_y = 0
        self.jump = False
        self.in_air = True
        self.flip = False
        self.action = 0
        self.update_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    def move(self,moving_left,moving_right):
        #reset movement variables
        dx = 0
        dy = 0
        if moving_left:
            dx = -self.speed
            self.flip = True
            self.direction = -1
        if moving_right:
            dx = self.speed
            self.flip = False
            self.direction = 1

        #jump
        if self.jump == True and self.in_air == False:
            self.vel_y = -11
            self.jump = False
            self.in_air = True

        #apply gravity
        self.vel_y += GRAVITY
        if self.vel_y >10:
            self.vel_y = 10
        dy += self.vel_y

        #Check collision
        if self.rect.bottom +dy >600:
            dy = 600 -self.rect.bottom
            self.in_air = False

        #Update rect position
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy

    def update_action(self,new_action):
        if new_action != self.action:
            self.action = new_action

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.image,self.flip,False),self.rect)


MainCharacter = Character(200,200,2,5)


run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    draw_bg()
    MainCharacter.draw()
    # update player actions
    if MainCharacter.alive:
        if MainCharacter.in_air:
            MainCharacter.update_action(2)
        elif moving_right or moving_left:
            MainCharacter.update_action(1)
        else:
            MainCharacter.update_action(0)
        MainCharacter.move(moving_left,moving_right)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Quit game
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    #         keyboard presses
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                moving_left = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                moving_right = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_w and MainCharacter.alive:
                MainCharacter.jump = True
        #Keyboard button released
            if event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    moving_left = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    moving_right = False
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: `if event.type==pygame.KEYUP:` is inside the `if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:` block. Move it back one level.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code is not indented correctly:

```
  if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
         if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            moving_left = True
         if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            moving_right = True
         if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            run = False
         if event.key == pygame.K_w and MainCharacter.alive:
            MainCharacter.jump = True
    #Keyboard button released
  if event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
         if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            moving_left = False
         if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            moving_right = False
 pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

I think this should work but i am not sure try it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).